# PHP OOP query() error - Call to undefined method connection::query()

Tags: php, mysql, oop

Im trying to insert data into mysql database.
I have class connection

```
    class connection{
function __construct(){
    $servername = 'localhost';
    $username = 'root';
    $password = '';
    $database='products2';

    // Create connection
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password,$database);

    // Check connection
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
        return false;
    }else{
        echo "succesful connection!</br>";
        $this->query=$conn;
        return true;
    }       
}
}
```

And another class in witch I try to insert data into database(i try  to do this in __construct of that class)

```
$sql="INSERT INTO products (name,price,category,f_material,f_size) VALUES ('nosaukums','cena','kategorija,'materials','izmers')";
$db=new connection();
$result=$db->query($sql);
```

However I get this errror:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined method connection::query() in ....

Comment: The class connection, does not have a query() method. The mysqli object created within the __construct() method DOES have this,

Comment: The error is pretty self explanatory..there is no method named `query` in your `connection` class

Comment: Looking at official php documentation [http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php]  I understood that its a built in function. So im wrong about that? @CT14.IT

Comment: No, you're not wrong as such but... YOUR `connection` class does not have this method. the `mysqli` class DOES. When you call `$db->query()` you're trying to call the method on the `connection` class, which obviously doesn't exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to use the query (from mysqli class) method you need to create a new method `public function query() {}`. This method will be able to use the mysqli method. In the end, you will be able to acheive the same result but by applying 'query' on your own object ($db) like so `$result = $db->query($sql);`

Here's the class :

```
<?php

class connection{

  // define a variable for the database connection
  private $conn;

  // when an instance of 'connection' class is created a connection is made through mysqli
  public function __construct()
  {
    $servername = 'localhost';
    $username = 'root';
    $password = '';
    $database='products2';

    // the connection is stored inside the private variable
    $this->conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password,$database);

    // Check connection
    if ($this->conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $this->conn->connect_error);
        return false;
    } else{
        echo "succesful connection!</br>";
        return true;
    }       
  }

  // method used to send a query to database
  public function query($sql)
  {
    // here you use the connection made on __construct() and apply the method query. Basically we are using inside our method (called query) a method (call query too) from the mysqli class
    $this->conn->query($sql);
    return true;
  }

}
```

Calling the method :

```
<?php

    // prepare the SQL request
    $sql = "INSERT INTO products (name,price,category,f_material,f_size) VALUES ('nosaukums','cena','kategorija,'materials','izmers')";

    // create a new instance of the class connection
    $db = new connection();

    // run the method $sql on the newly created instance $db
    $result = $db->query($sql);
```

Comment: `$this->db` or `$this->conn`?

Comment: @ivan Its working. As I understand this part : `$this->conn->query($sql);` from query() function already calls mysqli class right?

Comment: Yes ! I've added a comment just above that part of the code : we're using the query method from the _class mysqli_ inside our own _class connection_. That's how you can use the method in your own class...

Answer (score 1):

Because in your last line - `$result = $db->query($sql);` - you are trying to call a function named 'query'. If you look inside your connection class the only function you have is the constructor.

To fix this you are going to need to add a function called "query" (note this is not an ideal name for the function).

Here is some commented code (not guaranteed to be error free!)

```
class connection{

    protected $conn; // add conn so that you can use it later

    function __construct()
    {
        $servername = 'localhost';
        $username = 'root';
        $password = '';
        $database='_mvc';

        // Assign $this->conn to a database object
        $this->conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $database);

        // Remember we are checking >>THIS<< conn now
        if ($this->conn->connect_error) {
            die("Connection failed: " . $this->conn->connect_error);
            return false;
        }else{
            // no need to assign anthing here as the database object has already been assigned to $this->conn
            echo "succesful connection!</br>";
            return true;
        }
    }

    // here is the missing function
    public function query($sql) {
        // now we are accessing the database objects query method and massing the SQL
        return $this->conn->query($sql);
    }
}

$sql =
"INSERT INTO products (name,price,category,f_material,f_size)
 VALUES ('nosaukums','cena','kategorija,'materials','izmers')";

$db = new connection();
$result = $db->query($sql);
```

I would recommend you jump straight into php data objects and be done with it because PDO is the best 'standard' way to access databases these days.